# How to delete from Firebase with React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add a delete button to a post so that I can delete individual posts from a channel. I'm using Firebase as my database and the posts collections are nested within channels collection. I added a button to each post, created an onClick event called handleDel, I've tried finding the post inside the channel collection and deleting it but I can't delete my post.

const db = firebaseApp.firestore()

Post.js

```
function Post({ user, post, timestamp }) {
    const channelId = useSelector(selectChannelId)


    const handleDel = () => {
        db.collection('channels')
        .doc(channelId)
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(post).delete().then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        });
    }


    return (
        <div className='post'>
            <Avatar src={user.photo}
            />
            <div className="post__content">
                <h4>{user.displayName}
                    <span className='post__timestamp'>
                        <ClearIcon 
                            className='clearIcon'
                            onClick={handleDel}
                            id={post.id}
                            />
                        {new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()}
                    </span>
                </h4>
                <p className='post__text'>
                    {post}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Posts.js for more context

```
function Posts() {
    const user = useSelector(selectUser)
    const channelId = useSelector(selectChannelId)
    const channelName = useSelector(selectChannelName)

    const [input, setInput] = useState('')
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (channelId) {
            db.collection('channels')
                .doc(channelId)
                .collection('posts')
                .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')
                .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
                    setPosts(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
            )
        }
        }, [channelId])

    const sendPost = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        db.collection('channels')
            .doc(channelId)
            .collection('posts')
            .add({
                timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                post: input,
                user: user,
            })
            setInput('')
        }

    return (
        <div className='posts__container'>
            <ChannelTitle channelName={channelName} />
                <div className="posts">
                    {posts.map((post) => (
                    <Post
                        timestamp={post.timestamp}
                        post={post.post}
                        user={post.user}
                        id={post.id}
                        key={post.id}
                    />
                    ))}
                </div>
            <div className="post__input">
                <AddCircleIcon />
                <form>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder={`Post to #${channelName}`}
                        value={input}
                        disabled={!channelId}
                        onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}/>
                    <button 
                        type='submit'
                        className='post__inputButton'
                        onClick={sendPost}>
                        Send</button>
                </form>
                <div className="post__inputIcons">
                    <GifIcon />
                    <EmojiEmotionsIcon />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've also tried

```
    const handleDel = () => {
        db.collection('posts')
        .doc(post).delete().then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        });
    }
```

and

```
    const handleDel = () => {
        db.collection('channels')
        .doc(channelId)
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(post.id).delete().then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        });
    }
```

My console says "Document successfully deleted!" but the post is still in the database and still shows. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these lines:

```js
(<Post
    timestamp={post.timestamp}
    post={post.post}
    user={post.user}
    id={post.id}
    key={post.id}
/>)
```

```js
function Post({ user, post, timestamp }) {
```

Here, you pass in the properties `id`, `post`, `timestamp`, and `user` into your component but only pull out `post`, `timestamp`, and `user`. In addition, `post` here is not the `post` object (that has `id`, `timestamp`, etc inside it) but is the text content of the post, originally the value of `input` when posted, as a string. This means that your `Post` component doesn't know it's own ID as `post.id` in this case would be `undefined`. Plus, because you are deleting the document using `.doc(post)`, the delete operation succeeds because you end up deleting a document that is named with the content of your message like  `/channels/${channelId}/posts/"This is my message!"` instead of what you are trying to delete, which is `/channels/${channelId}/posts/${postId}`.

To correct this, you would change it to:

```js
function Post({ id: postId, user, post, timestamp }) {
  const channelId = useSelector(selectChannelId)

  const handleDel = () => {
    return db.collection('channels') // note return of promise chain
      .doc(channelId)
      .collection('posts')
      .doc(postId)
      .delete()
      .then(
        () => {
          console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        }
      );
  }

  /* ... rest of component ... */
}
```

Other things of concern:

- Rename your document's `post` field to `content` or similar to disambiguate between your post as a whole and its content
- Use `postData` instead of just `post` and `postDataList`/`postDataArray` instead of just `posts` to disambiguate them or make use of TypeScript to help catch these typos
- For each post, you are calling `useSelector` to obtain the `channelId`. Which is fine, but as there is a clear parent-child relationship here, you could pass in the `channelId` along with the post's data from your `Posts` component for improved performance.
- The channel listener (`useEffect(/* ... */, [channelId])`) doesn't clean up after itself
- The posts in the channel are not paginated. (Imagine a month-old conversation chain of hundreds of messages with at least 10 users listening to the channel - do all of those users need all of those messages at once? - that's 1000+ document reads when you might only need 10 per user)
- The `sendPost` click handler doesn't wait for confirmation that the message was send before clearing it's input
- The `sendPost` click handler doesn't show an error when `channelId` is falsy
- The `sendPost` click handler doesn't show an error on failure to add the message to the database
- The `sendPost` click handler allows posting empty messages
- The *Send* button is not disabled when `channelId` is falsy
- The value of `user` isn't error-checked, it is also unclear if this is a `User` object, their name or their UID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You need to pass unique id of post/list in API call to delete specific database entry

improved

```
<ClearIcon 
    className='clearIcon'
    onClick={() => handleDel(post.id)}
    id={post.id}
 />
```

function

```
const handleDel = (id) => {
        db.collection('channels')
        .doc(channelId)
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(id).delete().then(() => {
            console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        });
    }
```